# Getting Error when the Current Location is off the Route

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

i'm new to mapb box and i'm developing sample app to learn.
I'm using Custom Routes and user will navigate through the Custom Route when they start to Navigate.

Error occurs when the user's current location is off the Route. Rerouting is Disabled

DirectionsRoute getting from another Activity that Generated from Map Matching API

Code -

```
    val mapboxNavigationOptions = MapboxNavigation
        .defaultNavigationOptionsBuilder(this, getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
        .build()

    mapboxNavigation = MapboxNavigation(mapboxNavigationOptions)
    mapboxNavigation.setRerouteController(null)

    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView)
    navigationView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    navigationView.initialize(this, getInitialCameraPosition())

    private val routeProgressObserver = object : RouteProgressObserver {
    override fun onRouteProgressChanged(routeProgress: RouteProgress) {

        try {

            routeProgress.currentState?.let { currentState ->
                val state = currentState
                if (state == RouteProgressState.ROUTE_COMPLETE && routeProgress.distanceRemaining < 10) {
                    finish()
                } else if (state == RouteProgressState.OFF_ROUTE) {
                    Log.e("< <OFF> >", " off route > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >")
                }
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Nav Err", e.message)
        }
    }
}

override fun onNavigationReady(isRunning: Boolean) {

    if (!isRunning && !::navigationMapboxMap.isInitialized) {

        ifNonNull(navigationView.retrieveNavigationMapboxMap()) { navMapboxMap ->

            this.navigationMapboxMap = navMapboxMap
            this.navigationMapboxMap.updateLocationLayerRenderMode(RenderMode.NORMAL)
            navigationView.retrieveMapboxNavigation()?.let { this.mapboxNavigation = it }

            val optionsBuilder = NavigationViewOptions.builder(this)
            optionsBuilder.navigationListener(this)
            optionsBuilder.directionsRoute(route)
            optionsBuilder.shouldSimulateRoute(false)
            optionsBuilder.bannerInstructionsListener(this)
            optionsBuilder.enableVanishingRouteLine(true)
            optionsBuilder.routeProgressObserver(routeProgressObserver)
            
            navigationView.startNavigation(optionsBuilder.build())

        }
    }
```

Error Log -

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
            at java.util.AbstractList.subList(AbstractList.java:738)
            at com.mapbox.navigation.core.routeoptions.MapboxRouteOptionsUpdater.update(MapboxRouteOptionsUpdater.kt:103)
            at com.mapbox.navigation.core.reroute.MapboxRerouteController.reroute(MapboxRerouteController.kt:50)
            at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigation.reroute(MapboxNavigation.kt:687)
            at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigation.access$reroute(MapboxNavigation.kt:127)
            at com.mapbox.navigation.core.MapboxNavigation$createInternalOffRouteObserver$1.onOffRouteStateChanged(MapboxNavigation.kt:681)
            at com.mapbox.navigation.core.trip.session.MapboxTripSession.setOffRoute(MapboxTripSession.kt:128)
            at com.mapbox.navigation.core.trip.session.MapboxTripSession.access$setOffRoute$p(MapboxTripSession.kt:49)
            at com.mapbox.navigation.core.trip.session.MapboxTripSession$updateDataFromNavigatorStatus$updateNavigatorStatusDataJob$1.invokeSuspend(MapboxTripSession.kt:461)
            at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Can you provide your code? With this stack trace we can just guess what is going on.

Comment: @Moritz I have updated the question with Code sample

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing seems to stem from the double implementation of the `MapboxNavigation`.

This is indeed not obvious, but `NavigationView` is a packaged navigation plugin, that already bundles `MapboxNavigation`. Therefore if you want to go with `NavigationView` and not do your Turn-by-Turn navigation on a simple `MapView`, these lines are obsolete and can cause such problems:

```
val mapboxNavigationOptions = MapboxNavigation
        .defaultNavigationOptionsBuilder(this, getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
        .build()

    mapboxNavigation = MapboxNavigation(mapboxNavigationOptions)
    mapboxNavigation.setRerouteController(null)
```